# VHDL 'range => '0' command

Tags: range, vhdl, fpga

Was hoping someone could answer my question. I came across this command in a VHDL code and was not sure what it does exactly. Could someone clarify the following?

> if ( element1 = (element1'range => '0')) then

given that element1 is a 4 bit std_logic_vector, what is this condition saying? I could not find a direct answer for this in the few books I had or on google. 
Thanks!

Comment: Thank you everybody, for your responses

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's saying, create a temporary array aggregate the size of the range specified, with every element set to '0'. Whatever that range is.

Preventing accidents when the size of element1 changes.

EVERY time you see magic numbers like `3 downto 0`, or `for i in 0 to 3 loop ...` try to replace them with this or equivalent, because `for i in element1'range loop ...` will never loop off the end of your array.

The defined range is necessary because the relational operator `=` (like <, > and the others) doesn't restrict its arguments to the same length, so the simpler form of aggregate `(others => '0')` doesn't work, because its size is undefined.

Answer (score 2):

The condition will return true if `element1` contains only `'0'`. It is a way of writing this that does not depend on the size of `element1`. In this case `element1'range` is `3 downto 0`. If you were to change this to, for example, `5 downto 0`, the `if` condition would still work.

Answer (score 1):

`(element1'range => '0')` is an array aggregate with element choices for the range of `element1` and associates those elements with the value `'0'` creating a composite value that takes it's type from context - the left hand side of the "=" operator (IEEE Std 1076-2008  9.3.3 Aggregates, 9.3.3.3 Array aggregates).

The if statement (10.8 If statement) condition `element1 = (element1'range => '0')` determines if `element1` is all `'0'`s in a range independent manner, the equality relational operator (9.2.3 Relational operators) returning a BOOLEAN value.

This method of evaluating the value of `element1` is immune to the declaration of `element1` changing (6.4.2 Object declarations, 6.4.2.3 Signal declarations, 6.4.2.4 Variable declarations, 6.5.2 Interface object declarations).

The outer pair of parentheses for the condition (an expression) are superfluous in VHDL (10.2 Wait statement, the BNF for condition, 9. Expressions, 9.1 General, the BNF for intermediary target primary allows them).

Comment: What does `BNF` stand for?

Comment: 1.3.2 Syntactic description - "The form of a VHDL description is described by means of context-free syntax using a simple variant of the Backus-Naur form (BNF)".